# Attributing Copyright to Individual vs Business

Tags: copyright

An individual (e.g. Bob Jones) establishes his own business (incorporated as BJ LLC). He then self-publishes a book. Are there any legal advantages to copyrighting the book under his name versus the name of his corporation, or vice versa?

Comment: I edited it. In this particular example, BJ formed a sole proprietorship named BJ, then later formed the corporation BJ LLC. Does that mean he would have THREE options - filing under personal name, "business" name, and corporate name?

Comment: A sole proprietorship isn't a distinct legal entity from the sole proprietor (at least in US income tax law -- you report that income with your personal income tax return).  Did Bob write the book before or after forming the LLC?

Comment: Wow, this is more complicated than I thought. Let's say this book is published after the LLC is formed.

Comment: Where? in some countries you can't even transfer the "Copyright" (e.g. Germany does not allow to transfer the Urheberrecht at all) but only the commercial rights.

Comment: The question already indicates that the book was published after the LLC was formed.  the question is when it was written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states) [canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

In the US, "Copyright in a work protected under this title vests initially in the author or authors of the work," and "in the case of a work made for hire, the employer or other person for whom the work was prepared is considered the author" (17 U.S.C § 201). In Canada, there is a similar rule that "[w]here the author of a work was in the employment of some other person under a contract of service or apprenticeship and the work was made in the course of his employment by that person, the person by whom the author was employed shall, in the absence of any agreement to the contrary, be the first owner of the copyright" (Copyright Act § 13(3)).

Therefore, one does not really get to choose who the author and initial owner of the copyright are.

If Bob Jones creates the work, they are author and first owner of the copyright, unless Bob Jones creates the work as a "work made for hire" for BJ LLC, in which case, BJ LLC is the author and first owner of the copyright (or in Canada, Bob Jones would be the author but BJ LLC still the first owner).

However, the initial owner does not need to remain the owner. In the United States and Canada, copyright can be assigned in writing. Bob Jones could assign the copyright to BJ LLC; BJ LLC could assign the copyright to Bob Jones. So the question becomes what advantages are there to holding the copyright as an individual or to holding the copyright via an LLC.

#### Tax upon sale of the copyright

The answer is roughly the same as for any asset, not particular to copyright. If eligible capital property (which includes a copyright) held as an individual is sold, proceeds from that property would be taxed as part of one's personal income (perhaps with special rates for business income, but it would nonetheless increase one's personal tax burden). If instead the copyright is held by the LLC and sold, then it *could* be taxed as part of the LLC's taxable income and could perhaps be offset by losses incurred by the LLC. That depends on the jurisdiction's tax treatment of an LLC or whether Bob Jones has elected to have the LLC be a pass-through LLC for tax purposes (where that is possible). Which is more beneficial is entirely dependent on the particular circumstances of the individual and the corporation.

#### Tax from use of or licensing of the work

As far as profiting from the *use* of the work (i.e. via licences, etc.) nothing turns on who actually *owns* the copyright. If Bob Jones owned the copyright, Bob Jones could still grant BJ LLC a *licence* to use or sub-licence the work so that any profits from that activity would flow to BJ LLC. The same would work in reverse if that was preferred.

#### Standing to sue

Further, even an exclusive licencee would have standing to sue for infringement. So if Bob Jones granted BJ LLC an exclusive licence, BJ LLC could have conduct of any infringement suits in relation to the work.

Comment: Note there are jurisdictions where copyright *cannot* be transfered.